# Why does my sub class of qglwidget take over 3 seconds to construct?

Tags: qt

I have an image display widget which is derived from QGLWidget.  The problem I'm having is that the initial creation of this widget takes just over 3 seconds.  This causes a noticable delay between selecting an image to view and seeing the window appear.  Can anybody tell me what is causing this massive delay and any way I can avoid it please ?

I have simplified my code to this example:

```
class ImageDisplayTest : public QGLWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    ImageDisplayTest(QWidget *parent = 0)
            : QGLWidget(parent)
    {
            // empty constructor body
    }


protected:
    virtual void initializeGL() {}
    virtual void paintGL() {}
    virtual void resizeGL(int width, int height) {}
};

QElapsedTimer timer;
qint64 time_ms;
timer.start();
ImageDisplayTest* pTest1 = new ImageDisplayTest();
time_ms = timer.elapsed();

timer.restart();
ImageDisplayTest* pTest2 = new ImageDisplayTest();
time_ms = timer.elapsed();

timer.restart();
ImageDisplayTest* pTest3 = new ImageDisplayTest();
time_ms = timer.elapsed();

timer.restart();
ImageDisplayTest* pTest4 = new ImageDisplayTest();
time_ms = timer.elapsed();
```

The time taken to instantiate pTest1 is 3200ms and the time taken for the next 3 items is roughly 950ms each.  I am running on Windows 7 with Qt 4.7.4 and am using Visual Studio 2012 (express edition) to compile and run.  For comparison if I derive from QWidget instead of QGLWidget then the time taken to instantiate comes back as 0ms (i.e. too small to measure).

Answer (score 0):

That's the time taken to start up the OpenGL implementation on your platform. In Qt 5, on Windows Vista & up you can elect to use the bundled ANGLE implementation of OpenGL ES 2 that runs on top of DirectX.